# Using directory names starting with number in ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, geotiff-tiff, limitations

I have a script to export DDP extents to tif and when I change

```
arcpy.mapping.ExportToTIFF(mxd,"tests\BA\BA10k_" + str(ddp.pageRow.PageName) + ".tif",df,9306,9306*ar,1800,True)
```

to

```
arcpy.mapping.ExportToTIFF(mxd,"tests\BA\10k\BA10k_" + str(ddp.pageRow.PageName) + ".tif",df,9306,9306*ar,1800,True)
```

--added "10k" to the directory I get

> Exporting page 1 of 760 Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "P:\2012\183_TownPlanning_Symbology\Working\Raster_Layer_Creation\DDP_GeoTiff_production_BA.py",
>   line 10, in 
>       arcpy.mapping.ExportToTIFF(mxd,"tests\BA\10k\BA10k_" + str(ddp.pageRow.PageName) + ".tif",df,9306,9306*ar,1800,True)   File
>   "C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.1\arcpy\arcpy\utils.py", line
>   181, in fn_
>       return fn(*args, **kw)   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.1\arcpy\arcpy\mapping.py", line 1373, in
>   ExportToTIFF
>       layout.exportToTIFF(*args) AttributeError: DataFrameObject: Error in executing ExportToTIFF

Any ideas on why?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`\` is an [escape character](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_character) in Python.

You will need to either:

- Escape each `\` with another `\`
- Put an `r` before the opening quote to denote it as a [raw string](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raw_string#Raw_strings)
- Change each `\` to a `/`

---

[Your symptom](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/37231/does-arcpy-have-an-issue-with-directory-names-starting-with-a-number#comment48873_37232) of seeing that it seemed to "work without the '\' except if a number was the first character of the directory name" is probably because they weren't valid escape sequences and it was falling back to the literal interpretation. `\0`, `\1`, `\2` .. `\7`, are octal numbers which are translated into ASCII characters, thus mangling your pathnames. More info here: http://docs.python.org/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals